# Como fazer funcionar o botão "Voltar" do browser num site com AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Pesquisei este tópico há um ano atrás quando fiz um site com recursos do tipo `$.load()` e `$.ajax()` em AJAX/jQuery mas não consegui nada satisfatório que não fosse excessivamente complexo, e até hoje o site volta para a página inicial quando o usuário clica no botão `Voltar` do browser.

**Qual seria um método simples para restaurar o estado anterior, antes do browser receber os novos dados via AJAX?**

**Qual o melhor método para "imprimir" na URL do browser uma mudança referente ao alvo que o AJAX está buscando?** Do mesmo modo que acontece quando você clica numa imagem no *Facebook* e ele muda a URL mesmo tendo obtido os dados via AJAX.

Gostaria de utilizar as URL no mesmo estilo em que faço as chamadas ajax: `dominio.com/aplicativo/controlador/ação/parâmetros` ao invés de usar #.

Comment: Estive duas horas a preparar uma resposta, mas agora a tua pergunta indica um detalhe que a inviabiliza _de certa forma_!!! Vou deixar ficar de qualquer maneira pois lida com a maior parte dos problemas apresentados. Só não soluciona a questão de usar algo que não a _hash_ para controlar o URL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Introdução

Para que os botões "Voltar" e "Avançar" que os navegadores disponibilizam possam ser utilizados num web-site cujos conteúdos são carregados de forma assíncrona, é necessário manipular o histórico de navegação do próprio navegador.

O forma que efectivamente permite realizar este tipo de manipulação sem uma actualização da página (*refresh*), é através do uso da *hash* de localização.

Sempre que manipulamos a hash da localização atual do navegador, o mesmo vai criar uma nova entrada no histórico de navegação. Isto vai então permitir que o visitante navegue num site cujos conteúdos são carregados de forma assíncrona, através do uso das setas de navegação do próprio navegador, sem efectivamente estar a fazer uma actualização da página.

---

## Necessidades

Para possibilitar a manipulação da *hash* da localização atual no navegador, existem três requisitos básicos:

- Ler: Recolher e processar o valor da *hash* na localização actual;
- Escrever: Actualizar a *hash* na localização actual com o valor desejado;
- Escutar: Detectar quando foi realizada uma alteração à *hash* e agir em conformidade.

Vamos ver como lidar com cada um destes requisitos:

- #### Ler

  Recolher a *hash* da localização actual

  Para ler a *hash* da localização actual, podemos recorrer a JavaScript e ler o valor da propriedade `window.location.hash`. O primeiro caractere vai ser sempre o indicador de *hash* `#`, que pode ser descartado.

  ```
  // ler valor e "cortar" o primeiro caractere
  var hashValue = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  ```

  Por questões de eficiência, vamos criar uma função para tratar desta acção:

  ```
  /**
   * Devolve a hash da localização actual
   * @return {string} Valor da Hash com prefixo '#' ignorado.
   */
  function lerHash () {
    return window.location.hash.substring(1);
  }
  ```
- #### Escrever

  Escrever um valor na *hash* da localização actual

  Para actualizar a *hash* da localização actual do navegador de forma programática, recorremos novamente a JavaScript e à propriedade `window.location.hash`:

  ```
  // atribuir valor à hash
  window.location.hash = 'pagina2';
  ```

  Mais uma vez, por questões de eficiência, vamos criar uma função para tratar desta acção:

  ```
  /**
   * Actualiza a hash da localização actual com o valor facultado
   * @param {string} str
   */
  function escreverHash(str) {
    window.location.hash = str;
  }
  ```
- ## Escutar

  Escutar e detectar uma alteração na *hash* da localização actual do navegador

  O navegador convenientemente dispara um evento sempre que a *hash* da localização actual foi actualizada ou alterada. Para estarmos atentos a esta actualização e despoletarmos uma acção mediante o novo valor atribuído, basta-nos configurar um manipulador de eventos usando JavaScript para ouvir este evento:

  ```
  /**
   * Escuta alterações na hash da localização actual.
   * @param {Event} e HashChangeEvent object
   */
  window.onhashchange = function(e) {
    // Fazer algo quando existe uma alteração de valor
    // ...
  };
  ```

---

## Uso da *hash* para permitir um estado "persistente" da página web

Para entendermos um pouco como tudo está a funcionar nos bastidores, vamos analisar o seguinte esquema:

[image: Sequência de Acções]

- Sequência de acção A: Cor Vermelha

  Aqui ilustra-se o comportamento normal do navegador, sem a implementação dos requisitos que vimos em cima:

  - Utilizador interage com a página;
  - A página actualiza a *hash* para abrir uma nova entrada no histórico de navegação;
  - A actualização da *hash* despoleta um evento que por sua vez vai chamar a função manipuladora;
  - Função manipuladora não faz nada.
- Sequência de acção B: Cor Verde

  Aqui ilustra-se o que acontece com a aplicação dos requisitos que estudamos em cima:

  - Utilizador actualiza o endereço no navegador ou recorrer aos botões "Voltar/Avançar" do próprio navegador;
  - A actualização da *hash* despoleta um evento que por sua vez vai chamar a função manipuladora;
  - Função manipuladora vai executar uma função *nossa* para actualizar a página;
  - Página é actualizada e não acontece mais nada (nenhum *refresh*).

---

## Exemplo prático

<sup>Como na tua pergunta não tens nenhum código para melhor ilustrar o teu cenário prático, de a adaptar qualquer resposta ao teu caso em específico, fica aqui um exemplo genérico.</sup>

Neste exemplo a página web simula a inserção de conteúdos via Ajax e manipula os elementos a serem apresentados ao utilizador, enquanto trata de criar novas entradas no histórico de localizações do navegador para permitir o uso dos botões "Voltar" ou "Avançar" sem causar uma actualização (*refresh*):

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Exemplo de navegação sem actualização da página</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li id="pagina1">
            Página 01
          </li>
          <li id="pagina2">
            Página 02
          </li>
          <li id="pagina3">
            Página 03
          </li>
          <li id="pagina4">
            Página 04
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <section>
        Olá, bem vindo à Página 01!
      </section>

      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

        function cumprimenta(pagina){

          $('section').delay(100).html( "Olá, bem vindo à " + $('#'+pagina).html() );

          $('nav li').css("color", "black");
          $this.css("color", "green");
        }

        function oraBolas() {
          $('section').delay(100).html( "Existe qualquer coisa de errado!" );
        }

        /**
         * Escuta alterações na hash da localização actual.
         * @param {Event} e HashChangeEvent object
         */
        window.onhashchange = function(e) {

          var pagina = lerHash();

          // aqui chama-se função X mediante o valor da variável "pagina"

          if (pagina.length==7)
            cumprimenta(pagina);
          else
            oraBolas();
        };

       /**
        * Actualiza a hash da localização actual com o valor facultado
        * @param {string} str
        */
       function escreverHash(str) {
         window.location.hash = str;
       }

       /**
        * Devolve a hash da localização actual
        * @return {string} Valor da Hash com prefixo '#' ignorado.
        */
       function lerHash () {
         return window.location.hash.substring(1);
       }

       $(function() {

         $('nav').on("click", 'li', function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           escreverHash($(this).attr("id"));
         });
       });
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

## Conclusão

Desta forma, *manipulando a hash*, consegue-se uma navegação consistente em todo o web-site, quer pelo uso dos links presentes na página actualmente a ser apresentada, quer pelo uso das setas "Voltar" e "Avançar" do próprio navegador.

O trabalho é todo realizado pelo evento ouvinte da alteração da *hash*, onde aqui deve ser chamada a função relevante que vai originar o comportamento ou alterações pretendidas.

Penso que consegues resolver assim os dois problemas na pergunta:

- Direccionar o visitante para determinada área sem *refresh*;
- Garantir que, se o visitante recorrer às setas de navegação presentes no próprio navegador, o web-site vai-lhe apresentar a página *anterior* ou *seguinte* conforme esperado mais uma vez sem *refresh*.

Comment: Parabéns pelo esforço! Ótima resposta!!

Comment: Parabéns pela solução! Isso é incrível!!

Answer (score 5):

Embora eu não conheça o suficiente para aprofundar no assunto, existe essa biblioteca **[history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)** que disponibiliza diversos métodos para manipular o history do browser que funciona tanto com html5 quanto html4.

Código retirado da documentação da biblioteca:

```
(function(window,undefined){

    // Bind para o evento StateChange 
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Nota: Estamos usando statechange em vez de popstate
        var State = History.getState(); // Nota: Estamos usando History.getState() em vez event.state
    });

    // Modificando os Estados
    History.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"); // cria {state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"
    History.pushState({state:2}, "State 2", "?state=2"); // cria {state:2}, "State 2", "?state=2"
    History.replaceState({state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"); // cria {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"
    History.pushState(null, null, "?state=4"); // cria {}, '', "?state=4"
    History.back(); // acessa {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"
    History.back(); // acessa {state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"
    History.back(); // acessa {}, "Home Page", "?"
    History.go(2); // acessa {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"

})(window);
```

A ideia aqui seria você criar um pushState pra cada chamada AJAX que fizer. Assim, quando o usuário clicar no botão *Voltar* ele voltará ao estado criado anteriormente.

Ainda, é perfeitamente possível usar urls como você mencionou:

```
History.pushState({state: 1}, "Editar 1", "editar/1");
```

E o browser irá exibir na barra de navegação `http://seudominio.com/controller/editar/1`

Comment: ao usar `back()` ele irá refazer o `DOM` da página de modo a retirar as alterações feitas pelo último AJAX?

Comment: Sim, quando o usuário do site clicar no Voltar do navegador vai voltar pro estado que você criou. Veja que com `History.back();` você está utilizando o objeto dessa biblioteca e não diretamente o `history.back();` do browser. Dá uma olhada no link tem alguns exemplos lá...

Comment: +1 history.js é uma boa pedida; ...mas não sei se é compatível com AngularJS...?

Comment: Não testei com AngularJS, na lista de versões não existe uma específica para Angular, porém existe uma que é citada como nativa que é o native.history.js

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução direta é a API de histórico do HTML5:

```
history.pushState( estado, titulo, url );
```

Para fazer um código mais completo e uma melhor experiência para o usuário, você pode implementar o `popstate` ao mudar o conteúdo, para que a tecla backspace ou o botão de "voltar" do navegador funcione corretamente, voltando para a situação anterior, de acordo com a sua implementação:

```
window.addEventListener( "popstate", function(e) {
   // Aqui vai o código para voltar ao estado anterior da navegacao
});
```

O primeiro parametro do pushState mencionado anteriormente (estado), serve justamente para guardar os dados que você quiser, para poder usar na função acima. Se preferir, pode processar a URL diretamente, e não usar o estado/state.

Eis um belo tutorial neste link: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html <sup>(en)</sup>

**[Aqui](http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/history/fer.html)**, um demo de uma galeria de fotos em ajax, com histórico, e seu respectivo **[source](http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/history/gallery.js)**.

> Notar que nos browsers mais velhos, os URLs funcionam perfeitamente, mesmo sem Ajax.

Answer (score 3):

Para isso você precisa auterar a URL para que o browser realmente volte. No caso do AJAX conheço duas formas, uma é com comentários de URL, o famoso hash (#) ou outro método que acho mais organizado embora você teria que tratar as URL's também por .htaccess, neste caso você usaria History API, mais especificamente `history.pushState` que é um método de alterar a URL sem redirecionar o browser.

O primeiro caso é simples:

location.hash = '!/teste/lorem-ipsum'

Observação: Usei "!" por uma questão de indexar conteúdo dinâmico, o google substitui "#!" por "?_escaped_fragment_=" para indexar conteúdo dinâmico. Você pode ler mais sobre isso em: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Um exemplo simples do segundo caso seria:

```
history.pushState(null, null, 'teste/lorem-ipsum');
```

Esse script já mudaria a URL e você pode usar eventos da API para executar seu AJAX quando a URL sofrer essa alteração, neste caso o evento `window.onpopstate`.

Comment: Interessante. Se tivesse um roteiro seria bem mais fácil conseguir concluir esta tarefa.